# Android MediaStore.Audio doesn't load all MetaTags

Tags: android, audio, tags, loading, mediastore

To get all local Music-Files on an android-Device I'm working with a ContentResolver, getting Data from MediaStore.Audio.
Here's an example on how I load all titles + their artist:

```
ContentResolver musicResolver = act.getContentResolver();
    Uri musicUri = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + "!= 0";
    String sortOrder = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " ASC";
    Cursor musicCursor = musicResolver.query(musicUri, null, selection, null, sortOrder);

if(musicCursor!=null && musicCursor.moveToFirst()){
    int titleColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
    int artistColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);

    do {
        String thisTitle = musicCursor.getString(titleColumn);
        String thisArtist = musicCursor.getString(artistColumn);
        //save them somewhere
    }while (musicCursor.moveToNext());
}
```

**So this code is working for about 75% of all the music I have.**

**But** there are tracks, where artist (and some other values like artistKey, Track, Cover,...) return null. But the title, album_name and artistId are loading correctly.

The Tags should be right (shown right on the Computer and other Music-Apps). Also the format isn't different to the tracks that are working.

Have anyone of you had the same problem some day and solved this?
All those missing Meta-Tags are not even loading with a `MediaMetadataRetriever`. I can't explain what's the problem with some of my Files and why other apps can load them correctly.

If needed, I can upload a working and a not-working Music-File somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed how to do it.

Some albums have only stored the most information (aristname, albumcover) **in one** (mostly the first or last) of the tracks, not all.
This is not very common, but about 20% of my albums had this, even they were bought.

So, if you are loading/displaying one of these albums, you need to go through all album-tracks until you find the one, where the information you are missing on the others is stored. 
I made it a bit different because of my other code, but I think this is the most understandable way to do it.